# getting new bean instances of referencing beans every time

Tags: spring

I have two queries ...

1) I have a query that beans are intialized in the spring container itself when the spring container is intialiazed and before the call is made to the get bean() method , this is the default behavior , how can I configure the application in such  way that bean should be initalized in container only when a call is made of getbean() is made, shall we declare the bean as prototype to achieve this.

2) second query is that first please go through the below example first...

```
 <beans>
<bean id="triangle"  class="Demo.Triangle" scope="singleton" >
<property  name="pointA" ref="zeropoint"/>
<property  name="pointB" ref="firstpoint"/>
<property  name="pointC" ref="secondpoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="zeropoint"  class="Demo.Point"  scope="prototype" >
<property name="x" value="10" /> 
<property name="y" value="20" /> 
</bean>


<bean id="firstpoint"  class="Demo.Point"  scope="prototype" >
<property name="x" value="10" /> 
<property name="y" value="20" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="secondpoint"  class="Demo.Point" scope="prototype">
<property name="x" value="10" /> 
<property name="y" value="20" /> 
</bean>
```

As indicated above that triangle bean is singleton and it references bean are protoype now when I access singleton the other refernces beans zeropoint,firstpoint and secondpoint are also initaizes only once with respect to triangle but Here I want that every time new instance of these three beans to be get created when the triangle bean is fetched , Please advise how that is achieable. is it achievable through my pojo implementing ApplicationContextAware interface, Please advise

Answer (score 3):

Instead of relying on Spring infrastructure (`BeanFactoryAware`) I recommend trying lookup method feature:

```
abstract class Triangle {

    public abstract Point createZeroPoint();
    public abstract Point createFirstPoint();
    public abstract Point createSecondPoint();

    public void foo() {
        Point p0 = createZeroPoint();
        Point p1 = createFirstPoint();
        Point p2 = createSecondPoint();
    }

}
```

Every time you call `create*Point()` abstract method, it creates new instance of `Point`. But how do you implement this method and how does it know which bean to return? Spring implements this for you!

```
<bean id="triangle" class="Demo.Triangle" scope="singleton">
    <lookup-method name="createZeroPoint" bean="zeropoint"/>
    <lookup-method name="createFirstPoint" bean="firstpoint"/>
    <lookup-method name="createSecondPoint" bean="secondpoint"/>
</bean>
```

Check out the comprehensive documentation: [4.4.6.1 Lookup method injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection).

Answer (score 2):

1. Its called [Lazy loading](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init)

   `<bean id="myBean" class="a.b.MyBean" lazy-init="true"/>`
2. - First note that your `firstpoint` and `secondpoint` beans don't have a valid scope definition (you missed the `scope=`)
   - Prototype scope means that every bean that requires a prototype bean gets its own instance. If would define multiple triangles which all have a dependency to `zeropoint` every triangle would a separate `zeropoint` instance.
   - If you need new point instances inside your triangle class (e.g. every time you call a method of triangle) the best way is to receive instances directly from the bean factory:

E.g.

```
class MyClass implements BeanFactoryAware {

  private BeanFactory beanFactory;

  public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
  }

  public void doSomethingThatRequiresNewInstance() {
    Triangle t = beanFactory.getBean("zeropoint", Triangle.class);
    // because zeropoint is defined as prototype you get a new instance everytime you call getBean(..)
  }
}
```