# New instance from autowired class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting new bean instances of referencing beans every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437989/getting-new-bean-instances-of-referencing-beans-every-time)

What is a very simple way to get a new instance of an autowired class every time?

I've explored session, request, prototype, @resource. None seem to provide the desired effect.

Comment: What is the "desired effect"?  The description you have provided so far sounds like prototype scope is exactly what you need.

Comment: The desired effect is I always get a new instance from the autowired class... I tried prototype, but I still get the original instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Scope("prototype")`

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class YourService{}
```

Comment: +1 And as an addition, useful examples here: [Spring bean scopes example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/)