# Inject two different instances of the same type with @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have the following class:

```
@Component
public class SearchComponent {
}
```

And it is injected to two fields in other class:

```
@Autowired
private SearchComponent errorSearch;

@Autowired
private SearchComponent successSearch;
```

The default behavior is to inject the same instance to both fields, and this is happening, but what I want is that `errorSearch` and `successSeach` be different instances.

It is possible to do this? How can it be done?

Comment: maybe this thread might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388480/new-instance-from-autowired-class

Comment: This kind of depends on how you want to manage those beans. I'm guessing they are configured differently, is this correct? Instead of using component scanning, you should explicitly define them as `@Bean`s or `<bean>`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add `@Scope` annotation to your component class:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SearchComponent {
}
```

This will avoid your `SearchComponent` class to be used as a *singleton* (default value for Spring bean scope), instead a new instance of the class is created for every `Autowired` variable.

Take a look: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes

Comment: But bear in mind that if you want to autowire errorSearch or successSearch in another class, you can't as the prototype scope will create new instances.